# This code compiles fine but file is not created?Please point out the error

Tags: c++, file-handling

I was just starting file handling and started to write the code to create, read and write using binary files, I passed the structure to it and tried to run it but i found out any file as specified in the code was not created in my directory though the code compiled fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    int student_id;
    char department[20];
    char address[30];
};
ostream & operator <<(ostream &out,Student &s1)
{
    out<<"Name: "<<s1.name<<endl;
    out<<"Student Id: "<<s1.student_id<<endl;
    out<<"Department: "<<s1.department<<endl;
    out<<"Address: "<<s1.address<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    Student s1;
    strcpy(s1.name, "Sandeep");
    s1.student_id = 1;
    strcpy(s1.department,"BCT");
    strcpy(s1.address, "New Baneshwor,Kathmandu");
    fstream file;  //file part
    file.open("Student.dat",ios::in | ios::out |ios::binary); //create a file
    file.write((char*)(&s1),sizeof(Student)); //write to it
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"nice"; //check if it's open(code not running)
    }
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read((char*)(&s1),sizeof(Student)); //read from a file just created
    cout<<s1;
    if(file.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Cannot create file"; //check if file is not created
    }
    file.close();

}
```

Comment: file is not created and i checked that but don't know why?

Comment: Are you sure the directory is the one you expect?

Comment: You should probably check `is_open` before `write`. Does your program print "nice"? What is your working directory? Is it where you think it is? Do you have write access? Did you try hard coding a full path?

Comment: yeah, It should be in the one where this code is
and the results are similar for other file handling codes like this too and they work

Comment: No, nice is not printed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `ios::in | ios::out`, the file must already exist. You can do:

```
file.open("Student.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
if ( !file.is_open() ) {
   file.clear();
   file.open("Student.dat", ios::out | ios::binary );
   file.close();
   file.open("Student.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
}
```

Shamelessly stolen [from here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open#Example)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.
But using fstream, it should create a file if it doesn't exist, no?

Comment: Not with `ios::in`, afaik. I think `ios::in` always required the file to exist. `ios::out` does not.

Comment: @SandeepAcharya or instead if you're cool with overwriting the file(if it exists), you can just add `ios::trunc` to your open() along with the other flags you're having.